# java 9 resources

Tags: java, gradle, модули

Вообщем штука такая
Я пытаюсь получить InputStream через `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/fxml/auth.fxml")`. Этот код отлично работает на Java 8 или если я не использую модули, но если я их все таки использую, этот метод всегда выдает null.
Для сборки я использую Gradle в IntelliJ IDEA. И так как там ресурсы и классы лежат отдельно, у меня есть подозрение что штука может быть в этом, но я не уверен и тем более не знаю как чинить.
Если мое предположение верно, скажите как правильно настроить Gradle/IDEA для работы с Java 9, а если нет скажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился внезапно
Я добавил две строки в build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

и

```
idea.module.inheritOutputDirs = true
```

И это решило мою проблему